# pyautogui 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: pyautogui

I'm just trying to make a simple auto incremental number typer with pyautogui, not sure what I did wrong here, sorry, not too experienced with this type of stuff.

```py
import pyautogui as pg
import time

time.sleep(10)

def type():
    pg.typewrite(val)
    pg.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)

val = 11000
while(val!=30000):
    type()
    val=val+1
```

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

As stated abouve, all I'm trying to do is have a program that type a number, enter and then type previous number+1, not sure how the int type work in python

Answer (score 0):

`pg.typewrite` function needs an iterable parameter such as string or list type. You need to convert `val` to `str` type, not `int` type.

```py
def type():
    pg.typewrite(str(val))  # <<
    pg.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)
```

It'll work for you.

Comment: Ah right, type casting, thank you